# Validating event fired from other controls?

Tags: c#, events, validating

I have a CheckBox as part of a custom control on a form. I handle its Validating event to ensure that a maximum of 5 checkboxes have been ticked. If 5 have already been ticked, I cancel the event. This works splendidly.

Now, however, once I have 5 checkboxes ticked, *every* event is canceled (except unchecking the first checked CheckBox). This means that button presses, textbox focuses, combo dropdown and application exits are not working. The sender object is still a CheckBox; just not sure why it's being triggered.

Why is a checkbox's Validating event being triggered every time I do *anything*? (I would have thought it would only have been triggered when you click the checkbox control). Is using the "Validating" event the correct approach?

**Additional strange things:** No event is being handled when I select or deselect the 5th checkbox, despite having the event handler there. The same checkbox will trigger the validating event if it is the 4th or 6th checkbox.

**My Code:** Within the parent form:

```
    private List<MyCustomClass> GetSelectedItems()
    {
        List<MyCustomClass> result = new List<MyCustomClass>();
        foreach (MyCustomClass c in listOfControls)
        {
            if (c.Selected())
            {
                result.Add(c);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void validate(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetSelectedItems().Count == 5)
        {
             e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

The `Selected` method of MyCustomClass simply returns chkBox.Checked.

Answer (score 0):

How are you validating the input of a CheckBox? It is either `true` or `false`. Are you comparing that check to other states to determine if the current check state is valid?

Comment: What do you mean by the "input of a CheckBox"?

Comment: When you click on the check box and it then receives the value of `!chkBox.Checked`...

Comment: I look at all of the existing checkboxes for `chkBox.Checked`, and if there are already 5 with `Checked` being `true`, I set `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `false`

Comment: And by "`false`" I mean "`true`". That is, `Cancel` is set to `true`.